# Sum all numbers in a list of strings

Tags: python, list, sum, integer

sorry if this is very noob question, but I have tried to solve this on my own for some time, gave it a few searches (used the "map" function, etc.) and I did not find a solution to this. Maybe it's a small mistake somewhere, but I am new to python and seem to have some sort of tunnel vision.

I have some text (see sample) that has numbers inbetween. I want to extract all numbers with regular expressions into a list and then sum them. I seem to be able to do the extraction, but struggle to convert them to integers and then sum them.

```
import re
df = ["test 4497 test 6702 test 8454 test",
 "7449 test"]

numlist = list()
for line in df:
    line = line.rstrip()
    numbers = re.findall("[0-9]+", line) # find numbers
    if len(numbers) < 1: continue # ignore lines with no numbers, none in this sample
    numlist.append(numbers) # create list of numbers
```

The sum(numlist) returns an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the source of your problem:

`finadall` returns a list which you are appending to `numlist`, a list. So you end up with a list of lists. You should instead do:

```
numlist.extend(numbers)
```

So that you end up with a single list of numbers (well, actually string representations of numbers). Then you can convert the strings to integers and sum:

```
the_sum = sum(int(n) for n in numlist)
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out where I had my error, this works!

Comment: Everyone is trying to give you new ways of coming up with an answer, but I thought I would actually try to tell you what your problem was. Feel free to ACCEPT this answer if you think it is the best.

Comment: I did exactly that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a regex for this. Split the strings in the list, and `sum` those that are numeric in a comprehension:

```
sum(sum(int(i) for i in s.split() if i.isnumeric()) for s in df)
# 27102
```

Or similarly, flatten the resulting lists, and `sum` once:

```
from itertools imprt chain 
sum(chain.from_iterable((int(i) for i in s.split() if i.isnumeric()) for s in df))
# 27102
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate twice over `df` and append each digit to `numlist`:

```
numlist = list()
for item in df:
  for word in item.split():
    if word.isnumeric():
      numlist.append(int(word))

print(numlist)
print(sum(numlist))
```

Out:

```
[4497, 6702, 8454, 7449]
27102
```

You could make a one-liner using list comprehension:

```
print(sum([int(word) for item in df for word in item.split() if word.isnumeric()]))
>>> 27102
```

Answer (score 1):

It's as easy as

```
my_sum = sum(map(int, numbers_list))
```

Comment: OP's input is `df = ["test 4497 test 6702 test 8454 test", "7449 test"]`, not a list with only numbers

Comment: With the example given, this returns error: my_sum = sum(map(int, numlist))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-129-a36b633b9341>", line 1, in <module>
    my_sum = sum(map(int, numlist))

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Comment: This is regarding the summing part. OP said he did the extraction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `map`, `filter` and `sum`:
First splits the strings at the spaces, filters out the non-numbers, casts the number-strings to int and finally sums them.

```
# if you want the sum per string in the list
sums = [sum(map(int, filter(str.isnumeric, s.split()))) for s in df]
# [19653, 7449]

# if you simply want the sum of all numbers of all strings
sum(sum(map(int, filter(str.isnumeric, s.split()))) for s in df)
# 27102
```